# Page reloads even after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have 3 html files - start.html, loginPage.html and dashboard.html. When the login button is clicked, it should load dashboard but I am unable to access the button.

Start.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <title>Amazon App</title>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <br><br>

    <div id='content'>
        <center><img src='img/splashlogo.png'/><center>
    </div>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <script src="aws-sdk-2.1.34.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/check.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

loginPage.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function setValues(){
    $("#accessKey").val('MY-ACCESS-KEY');
    $("#secretKey").val('MY-SECRET-KEY');
}
</SCRIPT>

 <div data-role="page" id="start" data-enhance="false" style = 'background: url(../img/BG.png);'>
<div data-role = "content">
    <br><br>
    <div align="right">
        <img src="./img/help-icon.png" onClick= "setValues()"/>
    </div>
   <div align = "center">
   <img src="./img/Logo login screen.png" height="200" width="170"/>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <form id="loginForm" align = "center" data-ajax="false">
        <div id="user" align = "center">
            <input class="amazeFont" type="text" id = "accessKey" Placeholder="Access Key (20 characters)" size="30" maxlength="128" tabindex="1" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]"/>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div id = "pass" align = "center">
            <input class="amazeFont" type="password" id = "secretKey" Placeholder = "Secret Key (40 characters)" size="30" maxlength="1024" autocomplete="on" tabindex="2" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]"/>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <center><button type = "submit" id="submitButton" style='width: 80%; height: 40px; background-color: #f15a29; font-weight: bold; color: white; cursor: pointer;'>Login</button></center>
    </form>
   </div>
 </div>

 <script src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
 <script src="require.js"></script>
 <script src="aws-sdk-2.1.34.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/fun.js"></script>
 <script src="js/check.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
function init(){
   document.addEventListener("deviceReady", onDeviceReady,false);
}

function onDeviceReady(){
     window.location = 'loginPage.html';
     document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener("click", startApp,false); 

}

function startApp(){
    alert('switching page');
    window.location= 'dashboard.html';
}
```

The login page does not switch over to the dashboard page.It reloads. The button click is not caught. I want to make the pages slide.

**EDITED:**

the updated js:

```
function init(){
   document.addEventListener("deviceReady", onDeviceReady,false);
 }

 function onDeviceReady(){
     window.location = 'loginPage.html';
 }
```

Created a second js for loginPage.html and added it to the body of loginPage.html

```
function init(){
    document.addEventListener('deviceReady', onDeviceReady, false);
 } 

function onDeviceReady(){
   document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener("click", startApp,false);
}

function startApp(){
//alert('switching page');
   window.location= 'dashboard.html';
}
```

The dashboard.html is not being called

Comment: no in the end of body

Comment: In your loginPage I don't see where init() is being called.

Comment: it is called in the onload of the body of the loginPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the init() method from start.html which onload calls `function onDeviceReady()` which has a location change,hence other page loads.
You need to add the  `document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener("click", startApp,false);` when loginPage.html (maybe in a different function) page loads not when the start.html loads.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so if i were to create new function in a different js, will it get called when login page loads?

Comment: Yes,on the onload of loginPage.html

Comment: Tried it. Still not loading the dashboard.html

Comment: Can you update the code here or give a JSFiddle? @PallaviPrasad

Comment: THis should do it,your  `<button type = "submit" id="submitButton" >Login</button>` is a submit button.Change it to this `<button type = "button" id="submitButton" >Login</button>`  @PallaviPrasad

Comment: Thanks Varun. Working now.

Comment: I've been trying to debug my code the entire day and your comment solved it @Varun. Thanks so much!